# Sharing attachments from Mail App not working in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions, share-extension

I'm working on the app that has share extension.
Share attachment from Mail App with Share extension is not working. 
But sharing attachments(pdf, doc, image etc.) from gmail app working fine.

My swift code

```
        for attachment in contents{
            if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) {
                attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil) { data, error in
                    //Do action for image
                }
            } else  {
                if let item = (filePicker!.types as [String]).first(where: { (item) -> Bool in attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(item)}){

                    attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: item, options: nil) { data, error in
                        //Do action for file
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My **NSExtensionActivationRule:**

```
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
```

I never work with the sharing extensions before, so any knowledge that can be shared will be a great resource for me. 
Thanks in advance!